# Function to look for different patterns in specific positions in a string in R

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to create a function in R that searches in strings a specific pattern in a specific position, if the letter is present in the established position, I want to count it.

example of dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

mutations <- tibble(
  "position" = c(9,10),
  "AA" = c("G","G"))

strings <- c("EVQLVESGGGLAKPG", 
             "VQLVESGGGLAKPGGS",
             "EVQLVESGGALAKPGGSLRLSCAAS")
```

So, in this case, I want to look for the position `9` and `10`, if there is a letter `"G"` I want to count it.

Expected dataframe or tibble output:

```
| string | mut_counts |
|________|____________|
|   1    |     2      |
|________|____________|
|   2    |     1      |
|________|____________|
|   3    |     1      |
|________|____________|
```

In this example, all strings have a `"G"` at position 9, so they would all get 1, and only one of the three sequences have a `"G"` at position 10, so this sequence will have 2.

I am trying to use `str_locate_all()` from the `stringr` package to be able to locate the positions and then compare with my dataframe to count but I am failing to get what I wanted.

```
library(stringr)

.class_mutations <- function(sequences, mutations){
  .count_pattern <- function(x){
    df <- sum(as.integer(locating_all_patterns[[x]][,"start"] == mutations$position[mut]))
  }
  
  for(mut in nrow(mutations)){
    locating_all_patterns <- str_locate_all(pattern = mutations$AA[mut], sequences)
    counting_patterns <- lapply(locating_all_patterns, .count_pattern)
  }
    
  return(counting_patterns)
}

.class_mutations(strings, mutations)
```

I am getting this error `Error in locating_all_patterns[[x]] : no such index at level 1`, besides, if you have a better/faster way to do this, I would also appreciate it. **I have to take into account that this is going to applied in thousands of strings**, so I should avoid slow functions.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

```r
rowSums(outer(strings, seq_len(nrow(mutations)),
        function(st, i) {
          substr(st, mutations$position[i], mutations$position[i]) == mutations$AA[i]
        }))
# [1] 2 1 1
```

Walk-through:

- `outer` effectively just produces two vectors, an expansion of the cartesian product of the two arguments. If we insert a `browser()` as the first line of the inner anon-func, we'd see

  ```r
  data.frame(st, i)
  #                          st i
  # 1           EVQLVESGGGLAKPG 1
  # 2          VQLVESGGGLAKPGGS 1
  # 3 EVQLVESGGALAKPGGSLRLSCAAS 1
  # 4           EVQLVESGGGLAKPG 2
  # 5          VQLVESGGGLAKPGGS 2
  # 6 EVQLVESGGALAKPGGSLRLSCAAS 2
  ```

  (Shown as a frame only for a columnar presentation. Both `st` and `i` are simple vectors.)

  From here, knowing that `substr` is vectorized across all arguments, then a single call to `substr` will find the `i`th character in each of the `st`rings.
- The result of the `substr` is a vector of letters. Continuing the same `browser()` session from above,

  ```r
  substr(st, mutations$position[i], mutations$position[i])
  # [1] "G" "G" "G" "G" "L" "A"
  mutations$AA[i]
  # [1] "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G"
  substr(st, mutations$position[i], mutations$position[i]) == mutations$AA[i]
  # [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  ```

  The `mutations$AA[i]` shows us what we're looking for. A nice thing of the vectorized method here is that `mutations$AA[i]` will always be the same length and in the expected order of letters retrieved by `substr(.)`.
- The `outer` itself returns a `matrix`, with `length(X)` rows and `length(Y)` columns (`X` and `Y` are the first and second args to `outer`, respective).

  ```r
  outer(strings, seq_len(nrow(mutations)),
          function(st, i) {
            substr(st, mutations$position[i], mutations$position[i]) == mutations$AA[i]
          })
  #      [,1]  [,2]
  # [1,] TRUE  TRUE
  # [2,] TRUE FALSE
  # [3,] TRUE FALSE
  ```

  The number of correct mutations found in each string is just a sum of each row. (Ergo `rowSums`.)

---

If you're concerned due to a large amount of `mutations` and `strings`, you can replace the `outer` and iterate over each row of `mutations` instead:

```r
rowSums(sapply(seq_len(nrow(mutations)), function(i) substr(strings, mutations$position[i], mutations$position[i]) == mutations$AA[i]))
# [1] 2 1 1
```

This calls `substr` once for each `mutations` row, so if the `outer`-explosion is too much, this might reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: I tested replicating the strings 1000000 times to see if it would be too slow for this amount of strings, but it is still very fast. I am surprised!

Comment: The memory usage is based on `length(strings) * nrow(mutations)`. If `mutations` is practice will be significantly larger, then that's where the problem might arise. Glad it worked well!

Answer (score 1):

For a base R option, we can make sure of the string functions.  This approach compares the length of each substring before and after replacing the target character:

```r
nchar(substr(strings, 9, 10)) -
nchar(gsub("G", "", substr(strings, 9, 10), fixed=TRUE))

[1] 2 1 1
```

**Data:**

```
strings <- c("EVQLVESGGGLAKPG", 
             "VQLVESGGGLAKPGGS",
             "EVQLVESGGALAKPGGSLRLSCAAS")
```

Comment: I put "G" as an example, in practice, I have a data frame with many different letters at different positions. To use your approach I guess I would have to do a loop for each different "AA" in the mutations dataframe. is that it?

Comment: Well I can only answer questions which I can see, but you might be able to use an `apply` function over a vector of letter replacements, using the logic I have in my answer above.